# what are the consequences of not using a diode in a buck converter, and why a diode must be used?

Tags: buck

what are the consequences of not using a diode in a buck converter, and why a diode must be used? which component is most likely to break down in a buck converter circuit if a diode is not used?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 2):

In a synchronous buck, you're not using a diode (you're using a MOSFET), and things work fine. So it doesn't *have* to be a diode after all.

[image]

The purpose of the 'catch' device (be it a diode or a MOSFET) is to provide a conduction path when the series device turns off. The inductor current cannot ramp down without a closed circuit path - when the series device is off, the diode provides this path.

(The output capacitor in a buck cannot keep the voltage up without help from the inductor providing some current during the off-time, except in DCM when the load is very light.)